# "The specified child already has a parent" error using FragmentStatePagerAdapater

Tags: android, view, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I've tried to implement some of the solutions of all the similar questions but none of them seem to work in my situation. My situation is slightly different because instead of getting the surfaceview from xml I'm creating it through a SurfaceView class and adding it to a FrameLayout. I'm doing this because I want to use a mediaplayer when the surface is created.

Logcat

```
    07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3337)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3208)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3165)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3145)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout.wrap(NoSaveStateFrameLayout.java:40)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:915)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1064)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:911)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1432)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2268)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1159)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2545)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
07-12 11:02:28.221: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code is as follows:

VideoFragment.java

```
public class VideoFragment extends Fragment{
private static final String TAG = "Fuck this";
static String vpath;
static Context cxt;
static int pos;
static VideoFragment newInstance(int position, Cursor cursor, Context context) {
    pos = position;

    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    vpath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA));
    cxt = context;
    VideoFragment f = new VideoFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("position", position);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.full_image, container, false);

    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.framelayout);

    VidView vidview = new VidView(cxt);
    preview.addView(vidview, pos);
    return preview;


}

public class VidView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    MediaPlayer player;
    public VidView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        player = new MediaPlayer();

        player.setDisplay(holder);

    try {
        player.setDataSource(vpath);
        player.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {  
        if (player != null){
            if ( player.isPlaying() )
                player.stop();
        player.reset();
        player.release();
        player = null;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)   { 

    }

}
```

The Activity and the FragmentStatePagerAdapater

```
public class FullImageActivity extends FragmentActivity  {


private static final String TAG = "MediaPlayer shit";
//MediaPlayer player;
//SurfaceView surfaceview;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
Gridview gridview = new Gridview();
int width;
int height;
Cursor cursor;
ViewPager viewpager;
PagerAdapter pageradapter;
String path;
int position;
String[] projection = { GridviewData.ROWID, GridviewData.BITMAPPATH, GridviewData.VIDEOFILEPATH};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image_pager);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    position = i.getExtras().getInt("position");
    path = i.getExtras().getString("videopath");


    cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
                                gridview.mediaColumns, 
                                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA + " like ?", 
                                new String[] {Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Reelcam/TheReelcams/%"}, 
                                null); 

    pageradapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    //viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
    viewpager.setAdapter(pageradapter);

}


@Override
protected void onPause() {

    super.onPause();
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    //surfaceview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    super.onResume();
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    cursor.close();
    super.onDestroy();
}

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);        
        }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.i(TAG, "in getitem");
        return VideoFragment.newInstance(position, cursor, getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

}
```

Comment: When asking about an error, post the logcat output.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.full_image, container, false);

FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.framelayout);

. . . . . . 

return preview;
```

You are inflating `full_image` layout to `v`. But you are returning another view of id `frameLayout` which may have already a parent (probably `v`) in the layout. Return `v` instead.

Make sure you return a View which does not have a parent. Look into `R.layout.full_image` and see that if `R.id.framelayout` is already enclosed in a parent `ViewGroup`.

Comment: Yep that fixed it. Thanks. Now its returning a black screen any ideas on that?

Comment: @Papajohn000 Well, first use `HierarchyViewer` tool in SDK to confirm all UI is showing up good. Now, focus your attention on how to make stuff appear in that `SurfaceView`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the sollution :

```
public class FragmentItem extends Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
{
    View rootView;
    TextView textView;

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (rootView != null) 
        {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)rootView.Parent;
            parent.RemoveView(rootView);
        } else {
            rootView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.FragmentItem, container, false);
            textView = rootView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewDisplay);            
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What line is your specific error at? This is usually caused from adding a child to a parent multiple times. For example when you keep adding your surfaceview to the fragment and you set the content of the surfaceview to something new, the fragment still sees the same element. To avoid this problem just set

```
surfaceview = new SurfaceView()
```

set the surfaceview toe new content and add it back into your fragment.

I hope this helps.